# Array of Strings some positions are not printing

Tags: arrays, c, string

So, I have an array of strings and the first two positions are not printing, I'm pretty sure it's a size problem, but I don't understand why

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * switch(int i) {
    char letters[8][20] = {"Caio\0", "Eduarda\0", "Joanderson\0", "Heron\0", "Thiago\0", "Rafaela\0", "Thalisson\0", "Wilton\0"};
    if ((i >=0) && (i<=7)) {
        char*str = letters[i];
        return (str);
    } else {
        return "-";
    }
}


int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        printf("%d -- %s \n", i, switch(i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `letters` is a local variable. It exists only within the function. Accessing it outside the function is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: how do i supposed to return these values?

Comment: @kaylum: Re “Accessing it outside the function is Undefined Behaviour”: Accessing it after the function call ends execution is undefined behavior. Accessing it outside the function, as could be done in another function that is called as a subroutine and passed the address, is fine.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, that's what I meant. Good clarification.

Comment: @JoandersonPereira Change `letters` to store pointers to constant strings instead: `const char *letters[] = { "Caio", "Eduarda", ...};`. Also, note that `\0` is not needed as `".."` already creates a string which by definition is NUL terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve the problem:

1. Using dynamic memory allocation:

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    char *switch1(int i)
    {
        char **letters = malloc(8 * sizeof(char *));

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            letters[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
        }

        letters[0] = "Caio";
        letters[1] = "Eduarda";
        letters[2] = "Joanderson";
        letters[3] = "Heron";
        letters[4] = "Thiago";
        letters[5] = "Rafaela";
        letters[6] = "Thalisson";
        letters[7] = "Wilton";

        if ((i >= 0) && (i <= 7))
        {
           char *str = letters[i];
           return (str);
        }
        else
        {
           return "-";
        }
     }

   int main()
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
       {
          printf("%d -- %s \n", i, switch1(i));
       }

      return 0;
    }
   ```
2. Using static memory allocation :

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   char *switch1(int i)
   {
       static char letters[8][20] = {"Caio", "Eduarda", "Joanderson","Heron","Thiago", "Rafaela", "Thalisson", "Wilton"};
       if ((i >= 0) && (i <= 7))
       {
          char *str = letters[i];
          return (str);
       }
       else
       {
          return "-";
       }
   }

   int main()
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      {
        printf("%d -- %s \n", i, switch1(i));
      }

      return 0;
    }
   ```
3. I got an error, if I use `switch` as the name of the function. `switch` is keyword in C.
4. Lifetime of `letters` ends at the end of the `switch1` function. We have to use `static` or `dynamic memory allocation` to extend its lifetime to entire program.

Comment: that what i was looking for. Thanks dude. I named the function as switch to make my question more readble, i didn't notice the mistake.

Comment: @JoandersonPereira  You are welcome. Please upvote the answer, if it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`char letters[8][20] = …;` defines an array with automatic storage duration. Memory is reserved for it only during the function call. The statement `return (str);` returns a pointer to an element of this array, and then the memory is no longer reserved for the array. In C’s abstract model of computing, the array ceases to exist. In typical practice, the array is on the stack, but the `printf` call overwrites it.

You can fix this by defining the array with static storage duration, which reserves memory for it during all of program execution:

```
static char letters[8][20] = {"Caio\0", "Eduarda\0", "Joanderson\0", "Heron\0", "Thiago\0", "Rafaela\0", "Thalisson\0", "Wilton\0"};
```

Additionally, it is not necessary to include a null character at the end of a quoted string. String literals automatically include a null character at the end.

Also, string literals define arrays with static storage duration themselves. So, instead of using the strings to initialize an array, you could instead point directly to the strings:

```
char *letters[8] = {"Caio", "Eduarda", "Joanderson", "Heron", "Thiago", "Rafaela", "Thalisson", "Wilton"};
```

That array could also be made `static`. It will work either way (because your function will not return a pointer to an element in the array but will return a pointer, taken from the array, that points to a string with static storage duration), but, if it is made `static`, it will not have to be initialized every time the function is called.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning 1) `char *letters[8] = {"Caio", ...}` is the *CORRECT* way to initialize an array of 8 null-terminating strings, 2) it goes *OUT OF SCOPE* when the function exits, 3) *UNLESS* the OP declares it  `static`.  You should probably also mention `const`, and warn of the dangers of attempting to *modify* this array.

Comment: @paulsm4: Scope is where in source code an identifier is visible. Storage duration is when during program execution an object exists. I considered mentioning `const` but decide the answer already delivered enough concepts to digest for the question.

Comment: Scope: "is the part of a program where the name binding is valid, that is where the name can be used to refer to the entity".  The issue is indeed "storage duration"; the (generic) term "scope" is perfectly valid here.  Don't quibble.

Comment: @paulsm4: Scope is not “valid” here; it is irrelevant. Scope and storage duration are different things. The C standard defines them differently, with different sections discussing each. It is wrong to say an object cannot exist when a function goes out of scope. First, functions do not “go out of scope.” Second, an object can be accessed via source code outside the scope of its identifier provided it exists at the time it is accessed.